# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest doesnt work with token

Tags: powershell

Im trying to execute ansible tower jobtemplate API to check if the given template ID is valid. However, I am always getting unauthorized status code. Im generating token from ansible tower and sending it to next webreqeust. Below is the code snapshot of what I am trying to do, any clue what I am missing here. Does powershell support token based authentication or is there a different way to set a token in webrequest ?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
try {
    $json=ConvertTo-Json (@{"username"="*****";"password"="******";})
    $token = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.ansiblet.com/api/v1/authtoken/"  -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST).content | ConvertFrom-Json

$headers = @{Authorization="Bearer $token"}

$result = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.ansiblet.com/api/v1/job_templates/{templateId}" -Header $headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json").content | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host $result
}
catch{
    echo $site = $_.Exception.response
}
```

This web request isn't working.

Response:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                       
Token                          @{token=fcadd3e0326727e14f50401d4b8aaf91dc44ae47; expires=2018-09-14T12:30:11.546Z}                         
Authorization                  Bearer                                                                                                      
=

IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {Transfer-Encoding, Connection, X-API-Time, Allow...}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ContentLength           : -1
ContentEncoding         : 
ContentType             : application/json
CharacterSet            : 
Server                  : nginx/1.10.2
LastModified            : 9/14/2018 5:30:16 PM
StatusCode              : Unauthorized
StatusDescription       : UNAUTHORIZED
ProtocolVersion         : 1.1
ResponseUri             : https://www.ansiblet.com/api/v1/job_templates/1328/
Method                  : GET
IsFromCache             : False
```

Comment: Your not `Invoke-WebRequest` is missing a s in the `-Headers` argument

Answer (score 4):

Finally, Invoke-RestMethod did the trick for me.

Invoke-RestMethod $url -Headers @{Authorization="Token $token"}

I'm still looking for the solution using Invoke-WebRequest since my other calls are making use of it. Not sure what is failing, I have tried multiple solutions but did not work.

```
e.g

$headers = @{Authorization="Token $token"}
$headers = @{Authorization="Bearer $token"}
$headers = @{Authorization="Basic $token"}
```

Comment: English spellers note: Authorization with a "z"

Answer (score 0):

$token variable contains 2 fields - token and expires. Maybe it needs to be the only one token filed contents (fcadd3e0326727e14f50401d4b8aaf91dc44ae47)?

Comment: Sorry for little confusion here, I am able to get the token and its working fine. What is not working is this,  $result = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.ansiblet.com/api/v1/job_templates/{templateId}" -Header $headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json").content | ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: I tried this, however its not working. I am always end up getting "Unauthorized"

Comment: Try 'Token' instead of 'Bearer'.
$headers = @{Authorization="Token $token"}

Answer (score 0):

try this: change the line

```
 $token = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://stage-ansible-tower.hc.cloud.uk.hsbc/api/v1/authtoken/"  -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST).content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

to

```
 $token = ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://stage-ansible-tower.hc.cloud.uk.hsbc/api/v1/authtoken/"  -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST).content | ConvertFrom-Json).token
```

Comment: Sorry for little confusion here, I am able to get the token and its working fine. What is not working is this,  $result = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.ansiblet.com/api/v1/job_templates/{templateId}" -Header $headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json").content | ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: yes. i did understand that. did you test what i proposed?

Comment: Yes, I tried suggested change still its not working. I am getting same status code as "Unauthorized".

Comment: test your api calls with the browsable api https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/browseable.html